# Cannot insert duplicate key row in object '[Reporting].[SecurityPrincipal]' due to trigger '[Reporting].[SecurityPrincipal_Insert_UniqueName]

Tags: sql-server, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

Possible way to resolve Dynamics Ax Management Reporter issue:

**Cannot insert duplicate key row in object '[Reporting].[SecurityPrincipal]' due to trigger '[Reporting].[SecurityPrincipal_Insert_UniqueName]**

Answer (score 0):

This could help admins with Dynamics Ax environment integrated with Management Reporter.

After successful integrations we had the error "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object '[Reporting].[SecurityPrincipal]' due to trigger '[Reporting].[SecurityPrincipal_Insert_UniqueName]", probably due to pre-existing user records.

Solution(Maybe not the best)
1. Stop Management Reporter service
2.Go to MSSQL server for ManagementReporter database and execute the following;

```
ALTER TABLE [Reporting].[SecurityPrincipal] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
ALTER TABLE [Reporting].[ControlColumnMaster] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
ALTER TABLE [Reporting].[ControlReportScheduleTask] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
ALTER TABLE [Reporting].[ControlReportContributorSettings] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
ALTER TABLE [Reporting].[ControlReport] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
ALTER TABLE [Reporting].[ControlReportGroups] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
ALTER TABLE [Reporting].[SecurityCompanyPermissionIntegration] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
ALTER TABLE [Reporting].[ControlRowMaster] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
ALTER TABLE [Reporting].[ControlTreeMaster] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
ALTER TABLE [Reporting].[ControlReportSchedule] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

3. Delete all domain user records only. Do not delete the user "Everyone" and "Management Reporter"
   enter code hereDELETE FROM [ManagementReporter].[Reporting].[SecurityPrincipal] WHERE Name like 'domain%'
4. Re enable all constraints, start the service and hope for the table to be repopulated.

Hope this helps someone in need as I found no solutions online.